# Should ORDER BY change the result set?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I was under the impression that using an ORDER BY in an SQL query would not affect which records were selected for the result set.  I thought that ORDER BY would only affect the presentation of the result set.

Recently, however, I was getting unexpected results from a query until I used an ORDER BY clause.  This suggests that either a) ORDER BY can affect which records are included in the result set, or b) I have some other bug which I need to work on.

Which is it?

Here's the query: `SELECT node_id FROM users ORDER BY node_id LIMIT 100`

(node_id is both a primary key and foreign key).

As you can see, the query includes a LIMIT clause.  It seems that if I use the ORDER BY, the records are ordered before the top 100 are selected.  I had expected it to select 100 records based on natural order, then order them according to node_id.

I've looked for info on ORDER BY but as yet, the only info I can find suggests that it affects presentation only...  I am using MySQL.

Comment: Are you confident that what you mean by 'natural order' corresponds to MySQL's interpretation of the term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORDER BY reflects the order of all of the records before the LIMIT Clause. To get the result you want you will need this:

```
select u.node_id
from users u
join
(
    SELECT node_id
    FROM users 
    LIMIT 100
) us ON u.node_id = us.node_id
ORDER BY u.node_id
```

This way you will use the limit clause first and get the top 100 records and then you will sort the result of that. The join clause is faster than a double Select statement especially if you are working with many records.

Comment: Hi Natahn, your first sentence, ORDER BY reflects the order of all of the records before the LIMIT Clause, tells me all I need to know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested query:

```
SELECT node_id  FROM 
(
SELECT node_id FROM users LIMIT 100
) u 
ORDER BY node_id
```

Comment: this is slower than a join

Comment: How is this slower than your join?  You use a join and a nested query, while I only use a nested query.  As far as I can tell, your solution just adds on top of mine.

Comment: Yes, but you're joining on a subquery, which isn't the same as what that post describes.

Comment: did you do a test to see which is faster?

Comment: No, but I'd like to.  I don't have access to a large enough db at the moment so I'll have to test it out tomorrow.